# JavaScript problem toolbar=no

Tags: javascript, toolbar

I have a simple logon page.   When the user is validated, the window navigates to a new page.  The javascript is window.open('http://www.google.com',"mytest",'toolbar=no');   My expectation is that when it navigates away from our logon page and opens the google site that the back button would be disabled.   But it's not.      Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Where does the back button lead you to? Is a new window actually opening? Is there a fallback href='' in your link? Do oyu get any Javascript errors?

Comment: Are you looking to hide the back button - or - disable it?  Is it visible in the new popup window?

Comment: It takes me back to the logon page.   There are no javascript errors.

Comment: @Elliot: why would it do that? It's a **new** window: there is no history in that window yet for the back button to use.  I wouldn't expect it to go anywhere.

Comment: I don't see how IE8 would import a history into a new window. I'm quite sure the new window doesn't open up at all. Can you show the full link where this happens?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your browser.  Ultimately, all you can do with javascript's `window.open()` is tell the browser what you'd like it to do, but it's not obligated to do it.  Browsers can and do ignore some directives based on user preferences.

Comment: As a matter of example of what Joel Coehoorn is talking about, browsers typically will never hide the location bar anymore, as a security practice (phishing protection).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option your looking for is 'location=no', as that hides the address bar and therefore the back button too. The toolbar is things like favorites/etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice - what happens if the user has javascript disabled? If the browser prevents the js from removing the toolbar of the main window?

Instead, amend the logon page to detect whether the user is logged in before showing the login form. If logged in, show a message saying so instead of the form - that way, a user clicking back won't be a problem.

I find it very annoying when a website messes around with my browser window, and generally don't come back.

Comment: This is not a public website.   It is an internal application and disabling the back button will enhance the usability.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.   Instead of disabling the back key.   I listen for on unload event.    I then write the following in javascript:

window.onbeforeunload = function () {   return "You should not press the back button while in this application.  If you continue, your work will not be saved and you will need to log back in."}

Java Script pops a dialogue box with OK and Cancel options.    If the user clicks cancel.   The application stays right where they are.   The script is embedded within the  tags.   For me this is the ideal solution.    I found this at

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript